# Bug in JSON for HistoryServer REST API

Tags: apache-spark

I was wondering if someone has encounter the same problem before.

I'm trying to extract the information of a task list from one job. I do this through the REST API of the history server. However I'm getting only 20 rows of data while in the Spark WEB UI all the tasks are reflected ( more than 100 ). I attach screenshots and the log from the history server

[image: 121 Completed tasks]

[image: If I do a query against the REST API I only get 20 rows. It doesn't matter what tool I use to perform the query]

In the pictures above you can see how 121 tasks are displayed in the UI ( I won't attach the full screenshot of the 121 tasks because of lack of space ), however when I query the REST API I only get 20 rows. It doesn't matter what tool I use.

I paste here the log from the history server

```
16/04/15 09:23:00 INFO history.HistoryServer: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/04/15 09:23:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/04/15 09:23:01 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: abrandon
16/04/15 09:23:01 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: abrandon
16/04/15 09:23:01 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(abrandon); users with modify permissions: Set(abrandon)
16/04/15 09:23:01 INFO history.FsHistoryProvider: Replaying log path: file:/tmp/spark-events/application_1460638681315_0004
16/04/15 09:23:01 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/04/15 09:23:01 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:18080
16/04/15 09:23:01 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service on port 18080.
16/04/15 09:23:01 INFO history.HistoryServer: Started HistoryServer at http://172.16.100.1:18080
16/04/15 09:23:02 INFO history.FsHistoryProvider: Replaying log path: file:/tmp/spark-events/application_1460638681315_0005
16/04/15 09:23:03 INFO history.FsHistoryProvider: Replaying log path: file:/tmp/spark-events/application_1460638681315_0002
16/04/15 09:23:03 INFO history.FsHistoryProvider: Replaying log path: file:/tmp/spark-events/application_1460638681315_0008
16/04/15 09:23:03 INFO history.FsHistoryProvider: Replaying log path: file:/tmp/spark-events/application_1460638681315_0001
16/04/15 09:23:03 INFO history.FsHistoryProvider: Replaying log path: file:/tmp/spark-events/application_1460638681315_0006
16/04/15 09:23:03 INFO history.FsHistoryProvider: Replaying log path: file:/tmp/spark-events/application_1460638681315_0007
16/04/15 09:23:03 INFO history.FsHistoryProvider: Replaying log path: file:/tmp/spark-events/application_1460638681315_0003
16/04/15 09:23:22 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: abrandon
16/04/15 09:23:22 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: abrandon
16/04/15 09:23:22 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(abrandon); users with modify permissions: Set(abrandon)
16/04/15 09:23:22 INFO history.FsHistoryProvider: Replaying log path: file:/tmp/spark-events/application_1460638681315_0007
16/04/15 09:23:22 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing acls enabled to: false
16/04/15 09:23:22 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing admin acls to:
16/04/15 09:23:22 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: abrandon
16/04/15 09:26:44 INFO core.PackagesResourceConfig: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.apache.spark.status.api.v1
16/04/15 09:26:48 INFO core.ScanningResourceConfig: Root resource classes found:
  class org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.ApiRootResource
16/04/15 09:26:48 INFO core.ScanningResourceConfig: Provider classes found:
  class org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.JacksonMessageWriter
16/04/15 09:26:48 INFO application.WebApplicationImpl: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
16/04/15 09:26:49 WARN inject.Errors: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  WARNING: A sub-resource method, public scala.collection.Seq org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.OneStageResource.stageData(int), with URI template, "", is treated as a resource method
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be missing from the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api), but the `taskList` endpoint uses pagination to prevent too-large responses, with a default page size of 20, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/status/api/v1/OneStageResource.scala#L75-L88):

```
@GET
@Path("/{stageAttemptId: \\d+}/taskList")
def taskList(
    @PathParam("stageId") stageId: Int,
    @PathParam("stageAttemptId") stageAttemptId: Int,
    @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("offset") offset: Int,
    @DefaultValue("20") @QueryParam("length") length: Int,
    @DefaultValue("ID") @QueryParam("sortBy") sortBy: TaskSorting): Seq[TaskData] = {
  withStageAttempt(stageId, stageAttemptId) { stage =>
    val tasks = stage.ui.taskData.values.map{AllStagesResource.convertTaskData}.toIndexedSeq
      .sorted(OneStageResource.ordering(sortBy))
    tasks.slice(offset, offset + length) // <--- here!
  }
}
```

So - either use the `offset` parameter to get the next page, or add `?length=200` to the URL to get it all in one page.

(Haven't tried it myself though)